# how to get .app filename programmatically?

Tags: iphone

i when i compile the project a .app application is created. and it is same name as the project name by default.

how to get that name programmaticaly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSString *s = [d objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
NSLog(@"d: %@", s);
```